# Should I modify/extend the admin interface, or write my own CRUD views/templates?

Tags: django, django-admin

I'm trying to write a simple CRM app in Django; partly as a learning exercise and partly for in-house use.

My schema is slightly complex, as rather that have a single Contact model (with a home phone, work phone, home email, etc.), I have stripped down Cntact model plus a Phone model, an Email model, etc., with a ForeignKey pointing back to a Contact.  The point is to let Contacts have an arbitrary number of phone numbers, email addresses, etc.  Simple, right?

I have some working views and templates for displaying the data - no issues there.  And with only a very small amount of poking at admin.py I have a um...eight different TabularInlines set up, and the admin interface works to create and edit the data...but it's ugly and clunky to the point of unusability, and of course there's no conception of permissions or anything.  I'm also not really a fan of having a completely different interface for displaying and searching through the data than for editing and adding contacts...I'd like as much as possible to be done inline, so that I can search for a name, look at the record, click "add note", have it popup a form, fill in the details, click submit, and be done, all with AJAXy goodness so there's no page reloads.

Question:  Should I plug away at modifying the admin interface to try and make it usable for a user-facing app?  And if so, can anyone point me to a good guide or example where someone has really changed the admin interface to make it work for user-facing CRUD operations?

Or should I just go ahead and write my own CRUD views?  And if so, can anyone point me to a good guide or example where someone has written custom CRUD views that work with lots of ForeignKeys and inlines?  Ideally I want a form that displays a single Contact, all his Email records, plus a blank form to add a new Email record, plus a button to add more blank forms, plus his Phone records, plus a blank form, and so on for all 8 of my associated models.

(Or am I thinking about this all wrong?  Any advice appreciated.)

Answer (score 4):

For our intranet, we use ModelAdmin subclasses (not mounted on the admin site via admin.site.register) for most of our C(R)UD views. By using custom templates for the views, it doesn't look like Django admin at all. What is very convenient though, is that it already handles all the validation/saving for us.

In general, I found admin-"hacking" quite useful to quickly write up C(R)UD views and usually with relatively small changes to your ModelAdmin subclass, you can make it work for your use case.

So I'd vote for use ModelAdmin, but not the one you use in admin, hook a different template and come up with some fancy CSS.

Comment: Thanks for that; exactly the sort of answer I was looking for.  Unfortunately, I'm not sure how to go about DOING that.  :)  The documentation is a bit light; I guess I should just grovel through the code...

Comment: There's no documentation on doing that, since it's not exactly what it was built for.

Comment: +1 I do the same thing hooking Admin classes into my own url mapping scheme. There's so much built in to Django's Admin - validation, cascading deletes, authentication, and more. I'll try to remember to post some methods and code snippets on Monday when I return to work.

Answer (score 1):

I successfully created a software on top of admin.
The admin hooks (these days) allow very fine-grained customizations, i.e. in general you only need to touch what you want to change.

The changes can go from a trivial cosmetic adjustment to a complete swap-out:

If you provide templates/admin/base.html your admin site can look any way you like. And of course, a navigation bar at the top could include links to some of your own views. Watch out not to hardcode URLs in your links, always reverse.

You can overload ModelAdmin's "change_view", "changelist_view" etc. and swap them for your own views. For example I replaced a default changelist and its simple filtering with a search interface that allows dynamic queries to be built, result columns to be customized by the user, and loading/saving of these searches. That didn't affect any of the other views of that ModelAdmin.

Overloading a ModelAdmin's "get_urls()" let's you rewrap existing admin urls to go to your own views. I did the latter for one model where I wanted the simple Add screen to be replaced by a totally customized Wizard (only leaning on ModelForm).

Don't forget the simplest approach, esp. regarding your "AJAXy goodness": Just define "css" and "js" in your ModelAdmin's Meta. Want to move an inline from the bottom to sit between third and fourth field, and that's not possible via parameters? A one-liner in jquery.

Check out "django-grappelli" for an example of how to improve admin look and feel.

What did you mean by "and of course there's no conception of permissions or anything"?